# htaccess use one domain for 2 websites. domain.com/db to one folder and domain.com to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I really do not understand .htaccess files very well. I need some help. I have a AngularJS for my front end and Laravel for my back end. The Angular needs to communicate to the Laravel back end api for database stuff. But I want Angular to handle all of the front end stuff. Because of CORS and Cross-Domain issues I can't have them separate. So here is an example of my directory structure.

/mobile-app
  - .htaccess
  - /mobileFrontend
  - /mobileBackend

I really need it so that any time someone visits www.domain.com/db that they are routed to the mobileBackend.

Anytime anyone goes to www.domain.com or anything like www.domain.com/xxxx that everything else will go to /mobileFrontend so that I can let the front end part of the site deal with all of the rest of the routing etc. Is this even possible to do?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^db /mobileBackend [L]`